# BroadCast receiver invoking if screen is off

Tags: android

I am doing an app which lock the screen if we shake the phone, I had written the code for screen off,But now the problem is I need a broadcast receiver which checks whether the screen is off or on, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this [Link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

Which help to u better way to implement **BroadCastReciever invoking if screen is off in Android**.

**EDIT**:

You have to Add permission into manifest just like:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i saw this,If i go according to your link,Any modification in Manifest,(Example if we are writing a receiver monitoring reboot means we have to add BOOT_COMPLETED any thing like that)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to check whether the screen off or on at a particular moment, here is a good way for you, no need to register a receiver

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
if (!isScreenOn) {//lock screen
   //do something
}
```

In case you want to listen whenever the screen goes off, then you need register a receiver. For Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON you CANNOT declare them in your Android Manifest, but they must be registered in an IntentFilter in your JAVA code,and don't need to add any permission

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Then register receiver in onCreate of your activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
       //your code
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);            
    }
```

And unregister in onDestroy of your activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       //your code
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);         

    }
```

Hope this help you.